# Groovy @ListenerList generated fireXXX() method stops working

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to write a simple server which receives messages and distributes them to the registered listeners. I found [ListenerList](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/beans/ListenerList.html) annotation, which seemed to be perfect to eliminate the boilerplate code. It worked like a charm, all the methods were generated as expected, listeners were called. The only problem is that after some calls the `fireXXX()` method stops working and a `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown.

The `GeneratedMethodAccessor` part of the stacktrace makes me suspect that something gets optimized by the JVM and is the cause of the problem, but this is as far as my knowledge goes. I am pretty new to Groovy so I am also not that familiar what goes on under the hood yet.

Can somebody tell me what the problem is?

The listener interface

```
package connector

interface MessageListener {
    void messageReceived(byte[] mess)
}
```

The TCPConnector class

```
package connector

import groovy.beans.ListenerList
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel
import java.util.concurrent.*

@Slf4j
class TCPConnector {

@ListenerList(name="StatusListener")
List<TCPConnectorStatusListener> listeners

String host
Integer port
BlockingQueue<byte[]> inQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10)
BlockingQueue<byte[]> outQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10)
ExecutorService senderExecutor
Future sender
ExecutorService receiverExecutor
Future receiver
ServerSocketChannel ssc

TCPConnector(String host, Integer port) {
    this.host = host
    this.port = port
}

def start() {
    ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open()
    def address = new InetSocketAddress(host, port)
    ssc.bind(address)

    log.info("Accepting on $host:$port - $address")
    try {
        SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept()
        log.info("Accepted connection from $sc")
        startThreads(sc)
        fireConnectionUp()
    } catch (AsynchronousCloseException ace) {
        log.info("ace - shutdown ${ace.getMessage()}")
    }
}

private void startThreads(sc) {
    def senderThread = {
        log.info "Poller start"
        try {
            while (sc.isConnected()) {
                def taken = outQueue.take()
                log.info "poller ${taken}"
                def wr = ByteBuffer.allocate(taken.size())
                wr.put(taken)
                wr.flip()
                sc.write(wr)
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            log.info("interrupt $ie")
            throw ie
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage())
            stop()
            throw ex
        }
    } as Runnable
    senderExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor({ Runnable r -> new Thread(r, "Sender-$sc") } as ThreadFactory)
    sender = senderExecutor.submit(senderThread)

    def receiverThread = {
        try {
            ByteBuffer receiver = ByteBuffer.allocate(16384)
            int rec
            while ((rec = sc.read(receiver)) != -1) {
                log.info "received $rec $sc"
                receiver.flip()
                byte[] readed = new byte[receiver.remaining()]
                receiver.get(readed)
                inQueue.offer(readed)
                receiver.clear()
            }
            log.info("minusone")
            stop()
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage())
            throw ex
        } finally {
            try {
                log.info("finally stop")
                stop()
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("ex while stop ${ex.getMessage()}")
                throw ex
            }
        }
    }
    receiverExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(
            { Runnable r -> new Thread(r, "Receiver-$sc") } as ThreadFactory)
    receiver = receiverExecutor.submit(receiverThread)
}

def stop() {
    if (sender != null) {
        sender.cancel(true)
        receiver.cancel(true)
        senderExecutor.shutdown()
        receiverExecutor.shutdown()
        fireConnectionDown()
    }
    ssc.close()
    log.info("stopped")
}

static void main(String[] args) {
    new TCPConnector("192.168.0.1", 1234)
}
}
```

The connector class

```
package connector

import groovy.beans.ListenerList
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class Connector implements TCPConnectorStatusListener {

@ListenerList(name="MessageListener")
List<MessageListener> listenerList

TCPConnector tcpconn
Thread ConnThread

Connector(String host, Integer port) {
    tcpconn = new TCPConnector(host, port)
    tcpconn.addStatusListener((TCPConnectorStatusListener) this)
}

def start() {
    tcpconn.start()
}

@Override
void connectionUp() {
    log.info("Connection up")
    def recvMessage = {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                def mess = tcpconn.inQueue.take()
                log.info(" $mess")
                try {
                    printAllMethods(this)
                    this.fireMessageReceived(mess)
                } catch (NoSuchMethodError nsme) {
                    log.error("WHY????", nsme)
                    nsme.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage())
            throw ex
        }
    }
    ConnThread = new Thread(recvMessage, "Conn-${tcpconn.host}:${tcpconn.port}")
    ConnThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler({t, e ->
        log.error(e.getMessage())
        e.printStackTrace()
    })
    ConnThread.start()
}

@Override
void connectionDown() {
    log.info("Connection down")
    ConnThread.interrupt()
}

static void printAllMethods( obj ){
    if( !obj ){
        println( "Object is null\r\n" );
        return;
    }
    if( !obj.metaClass && obj.getClass() ){
        printAllMethods( obj.getClass() );
        return;
    }
    def str = "class ${obj.getClass().name} functions:\r\n";
    obj.metaClass.methods.name.unique().each{
        str += it+"("
        obj.metaClass.methods.find {m -> it == m.name}.each {mm -> str += mm.parameterTypes}
        str += "); "
    }
    println "${str}\r\n"
}
}
```

Output of printAllMethods(). Is the same both when fireXXX() is working and when it is not.

```
class connector.Connector functions:
equals([class java.lang.Object]boolean); getClass([]class java.lang.Class); hashCode([]int); notify([]void); notifyAll([]void); toString([]class java.lang.String); wait([]void); addMessageListener([interface connector.MessageListener]void); connectionDown([]void); connectionUp([]void); fireMessageReceived([class [B]void); getListenerList([]interface java.util.List); getMessageListeners([]class [Lconnector.MessageListener;); getMetaClass([]interface groovy.lang.MetaClass); getProperty([class java.lang.String]class java.lang.Object); getConnThread([]class java.lang.Thread); getTcpconn([]class connector.TCPConnector); invokeMethod([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Object]class java.lang.Object); printAllMethods([class java.lang.Object]void); removeMessageListener([interface connector.MessageListener]void); setListenerList([interface java.util.List]void); setMetaClass([interface groovy.lang.MetaClass]void); setProperty([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Object]void); setConnThread([class java.lang.Thread]void); setTcpconn([class connector.TCPConnector]void); start([]class java.lang.Object);
```

Exception

```
12:25:12.544 [Conn-192.168.0.1:5555] ERROR connector.Connector - WHY????
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: connector.Connector.fireMessageReceived([B)V
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
  at connector.Connector$_connectionUp_closure1.doCall(Connector.groovy:34)
  at connector.Connector$_connectionUp_closure1.doCall(Connector.groovy)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: connector.Connector.fireMessageReceived([B)V
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
  at connector.Connector$_connectionUp_closure1.doCall(Connector.groovy:34)
  at connector.Connector$_connectionUp_closure1.doCall(Connector.groovy)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
  at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
  at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:495)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Has been resolved in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've condensed the sample code into an smaller version.

```
import groovy.beans.ListenerList

interface MessageListener {
  void messageReceived(byte[] msg)
}

class MessageProducer {
  @ListenerList
  List<MessageListener> listeners

  void produce(String msg) {
    fireMessageReceived(msg.getBytes())
  }
}

producer = new MessageProducer()
producer.addMessageListener({ println it } as MessageListener)
producer.produce('Groovy')
```

Running this code reproduces the error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: MessageProducer.fireMessageReceived([B)V
```

You can inspect the generated code when running it inside GroovyConsole (Script menu -> Inspect AST), resulting in the `MessageProducer` class having the following method

```
public void fireMessageReceived([B msg) {
    if ( listeners != null) {
        java.util.ArrayList<E extends java.lang.Object> __list = new java.util.ArrayList<MessageListener>(listeners)
        for (java.lang.Object listener : __list ) {
            listener.messageReceived(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is that there may be a bug in the Groovy method selection mechanism when array types are used as parameters for the fireXXX methods. It works perfectly well with non array types. I'd suggest heading to http://groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html and ask the devs directly before reporting a bug in Groovy's issue tracker.

Tested with Groovy 2.4.7.

Comment: Thank you! Nice tip with the groovyConsole. Will head over to the mailing list and ask the knowers.